# Playing with arrays in mongo DB aggregations

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Need help in converting an array of objects to a simple array list

One of the fields in my JSON document is as follows -

```
"joinResults" : [
    {
        "value" : "Spouses"
    }, 
    {
        "value" : "Children"
    },  
    {
        "value" : "Ghosts"
    }
]
```

Need help in finding the right function to convert this to a simple list that looks as follows -

```
joinResults: ["Spouses", "Children", "Ghosts"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a simple [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in an aggregation pipe;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      joinResults: "$joinResults.value"
    }
  }
])
```

will give out;

```
{
    //some id,
    "joinResults": [
        "Spouses",
        "Children",
        "Ghosts"
     ]
}
```

[See it on mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XjCHugcwTah)